# Adding operators while reading files

Tags: c++

i'm reading values off a .txt file that has been compiled during a scan that I did and once I checked it, the number of values are through the roof. I want to create a program that reads the values gained from the .txt file and check if the values are within the range that I set.

For now, my current line for these functions are:

```
std::string item , output, value;

while (getline(infile,value))
{
if (value <= -2.4 && >=-2.6)
{
cout << "Passed";
}
}
```

But the problem us that the if line says that no operators matches these operands. Any suggestions?

p.s. Sorry if the line is crude I recently started C++. Any help or opinion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You probably want `double value;` and `while (infile >> value)`

Comment: `if ( value <= -2.4 && value >= -2.6 )` . The `&&` operator (and indeed, every other operator) takes operands that must be standalone expressions in their own right

Comment: `value <= -2.4` won't compile. Comparing an `std::string` with a floating point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the problem is due to comparing doubles and strings a solution would be:

```
double value;
while (infile>>value)
{
    if (value <= -2.4 && value >=-2.6)
    {
    cout << "Passed";
    }
}
```

Comment: You should [check your answer](https://ideone.com/1rYUG6) to make sure it compiles.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I did and it compiles

Comment: @JakeFreeman I wonder which `value` could ever pass this test.

Comment: @JakeFreeman _"what is wrong with that line?"_ It's irrelevant.

Comment: @user0042 None but thats what the guy ask in question.

Comment: @JakeFreeman I tried out what you did, and from there I added a few more functions to count the number of passes and failures instead of using "pass" as I had about 400 000 values. But overall thanks so much for the help! I managed to do what I needed to!

Comment: @kylevargas It was a pleasure to help!